# How can I paste from my Android clipboard?

Tags: macos, monterey, copy-paste, android

On my previous Android (OnePlus) phone, my Mac's right-click menu would include "paste from ONEPLUS..." which was very handy. However, I have no recollection how I set this up - it just seemed to work.

My newer Android phone is not presenting this option; are there any settings in macOS pertinent to this to allow clipboard sharing with other devices?

Comment: I'd guess it was something 3rd party you installed. I can't see Apple themselves making any provision for Android.

Comment: @Tetsujin it looks like OnePlus may have something baked into their custom OS.

Answer (score 1):

@tetsujin is correct. It would have to be a third-party app for Android that was on the previous device.

The service that your Mac uses to do that, along with KVM functions, is called Universal Control, you can find it in **System Settings** > **Displays**. It works seamlessly with Apple devices on the latest OS versions, but it does require all to be logged into the same AppleID.

Do a Google search for "Universal Control for Android" or "Universal Control alternatives" to see what may be available. Please let us know if you find something that works.

Comment: There's no "Universal Control" option in my Display settings.

Comment: It's not strictly Universal Control, it's Handoff, a different part of Continuity; System Prefs > General - https://www.apple.com/macos/continuity/ There's a list of droid apps here - https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/apps-android-mac-continuity/ - I have no way to test any of them.